# Python Selenium: find and click an element

Tags: python, selenium

How do I use Python to simply find a link containing text/id/etc and then click that element?

My imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Code to go to my URL:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.get(myURL) # Load page
#right here I want to look for element containing "Click Me" in the text 
#and then click it
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Look at method list of `WebDriver` class - http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html

For example, to find element by its ID and click it, the code will look like this

```
element = browser.find_element_by_id("your_element_id")
element.click()
```

Comment: what would you suggest if one cannot find the 'submit' element to be clicked in order to proceed? How would you scan the login page to proceed? (my example url here: https://oneclicklcaapp.com/app/sec/util/getEpdFile?resourceId=INIES_IDOU20190612_102433&profileId=INIES2019)

Answer (score 6):

Hi there are a couple of ways to find a link (or any element):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("element-id")
element = driver.find_element_by_name("element-name")
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='element-id']")
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("link-text")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class-name")
```

I think the best option for you is `find_element_by_link_text` since it's a link.
Once you saved the element in a variable, you call the click function: `element.click()` or `element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`

Take a look to the [selenium-python documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html), there are a couple of examples there.

Answer (score 4):

You just use this code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://play.spotify.com/")# here change your link

wait=WebDriverWait(driver,250)
# it will wait for 250 seconds an element to come into view, you can change the #value

submit=wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, 'Click Me')))
submit.click()
```

here wait is best fit for javascript enabled website let suppose if you load the page in webdriver but due to javascript some element loads after some second then it best suite to use wait element there.

Answer (score 3):

for link containing text

```
browser = webdriver.firefox()
browser.find_element_by_link_text(link_text).click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try SST - it is a simple yet very good test framework for python. 
Install it first: http://testutils.org/sst/index.html

Then:

Imports:

```
from sst.actions import *
```

First define a variable - `element` - that you're after

```
element = assert_element(text="some words and more words")
```

I used this: http://testutils.org/sst/actions.html#assert-element

Then click that element:

```
click_element('element')
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it by xpath:

```
Browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@href='you_link']").click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Finding Element by Link Text

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("")
```

Finding Element by Name

```
driver.find_element_by_name("")
```

Finding Element By ID

```
driver.find_element_by_id("")
```

Answer (score 2):

First start one instance of browser. Then you can use any of the following methods to get element or link. After locating the element you can use `element.click()` or `element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` or any other object of `selenium webdriver`

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Selenium provides the following methods to locate elements in a page:

To find individual elements. These methods will return individual element.

```
browser.find_element_by_id(id)
browser.find_element_by_name(name)
browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
browser.find_element_by_link_text(link_text)
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text(partial_link_text)
browser.find_element_by_tag_name(tag_name)
browser.find_element_by_class_name(class_name)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector)
```

To find multiple elements (these methods will return a list). Later you can iterate through the list or with `elementlist[n]` you can locate individual element from list.

```
browser.find_elements_by_name(name)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath)
browser.find_elements_by_link_text(link_text)
browser.find_elements_by_partial_link_text(partial_link_text)
browser.find_elements_by_tag_name(tag_name)
browser.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(css_selector)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("")
browser.find_element_by_id("")
browser.find_element_by_name("")
browser.find_element_by_class_name("")
```

Inside the ("") you have to put the respective xpath, id, name, class_name, etc...